# Let $k$ be a number field, and $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^r$ a $\mathbb Q$-basis of $k$. Why is $k=\mathbb Q(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

When we say $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^r$ a $\mathbb Q$-basis of $k$, doesn't this mean that $k=\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb Q}\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r\}$, and therefore we can't get things like $\frac1{\alpha_i}$ which are in $\mathbb Q(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r)$?

Or can we somehow get things like $\frac{f(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r)}{g(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r)}$ ($f,g\in\mathbb Q[X_1,\dots,X_r]$) by linear combinations of the basis? Using minimal polynomials or something?

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Since $k$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$, every element of $k$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: You need to use that $k$ is a field (not just a $\mathbb Q$-vector space) containing $\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_r$. Then it follows immediately that $\mathbb Q(\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_r) \subseteq k$. For the other inclusion it is indeed sufficient to know that $k$ is a $\mathbb Q$-vector space containing $\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if $k$ is an extension field of $\Bbb Q$, then $k$ is also a $\Bbb Q$-vector space.

In your example, $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ form a $\Bbb Q$-basis of $k$ and so each element of $k$ can be written as $$\sum_i c_i\alpha_i$$ where the $c_i$'s are rational numbers.

This includes that the inverses of the $\alpha_i$'s belong to $k$ (as $k$ is a field) and can also be represented this way.

Think about $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2) = \{a+b\sqrt 2\mid a,b\in\Bbb Q\}$ with basis $\{1,\sqrt 2\}$.
Here $$(a+b\sqrt 2)^{-1} = \frac{a}{a^2-2b^2} - \frac{b}{a^2-2b^2}\sqrt 2.$$

Comment: No need to show this. If $k$ is a field over say $\Bbb Q$, then $k$ is a vector space over $\Bbb Q$ by definition and the representation of the inverse of a (basis) element is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of $k = \mathbb Q (\alpha) $ , if $f =x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} +...+ a_0 $ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ then ${\alpha}^{-1} = -{a_0}^{-1} ( {\alpha}^{n -1} +  a_{n-1} {\alpha}^{n-1} .. a_1) $ since $ f(\alpha) =0 $. Similarly we can get for other finite extensions also. (Here $a_0 \neq 0$ as it is the constant of minimal  polynomial.